# Find intersections in GPS tracks

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, gps

I’m embarking on a personal project (planning on starting in Python if it becomes relevant), and I’m looking for some algorithms advice.

One part of my project will entail finding intersections between GPS tracks. Not like identifying road intersections, but identifying places where two different tracks cross.

I can’t think of a way to do it that isn’t heinously computationally intensive, but I feel like this is a problem that has probably been studied/solved in the past. Is there a name for this type of problem? Or are there algorithms that I should look in to?

Comment: What is a "GPS track"?

Comment: To me a GPS track is the record of someone's/something's movements as recorded by a GPS device (e.g. a GPX file). For instance, you could put a GPS tracker on a dog and go play in a park, and you'd end up with a squiggle all over the park. 

The data at its core is sets of latitude/logitude/timestamp triplets (plus potentially a whole host of other data).

Comment: Shouldn't sampling work here? eg. You can divide the whole GPS-track into, say, 10m block-samples and find a way to coordinate them (Like location latitude-longitude). Then, your GPS-track will be represented as a set of points. To find intersection between multiple tracks, you would need intersecting points.

Comment: You can speed up, by storing the line segments of the tracks in a geo spatial index.  Either a simplex fixed grid, with grid cell height/width, e.g 100m. (expressed as longitude). Then for a given line segment in track A, you find the all grid cells, the line seg, intersect, and now just check for intersection with the line segs you found in the grid cells. That is simple enough to implement in your personal project. Ad professional solution would use a quad tree to store the geo index.

Answer (score 1):

No "clever" algorithm there. You use all positions of a given mobile object to make the track (really, it's more the "history of movement" rather than a track), you obtain a polyline.

To check intersections between two mobile elements, you'll have to find where the two polylines intersects. You simply check each segment of the first track with each segment of the second track.

You can optimize a lot by using a bounding rectangle around the polylines: if the two bounding rectangles do not intersect, no need to check, there is no intersections. Otherwise, get the intersection, and you can directly ignore all segments that are outside this intersection area.

Once an intersection is found, you can then compare the plot timestamp in order to see if the two mobile objects did really meet, or if they simply crossed the other one's path at a different time.

If needed, once you found an intersection on projected polyline, you can also check the altitude, too, because the polyline is indeed in 3D and not only in 2D - GPS give altitude, too.